# How to installing Windows 10 Phone in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to develop Windows 10 Mobile applications. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and I installed Qt 5.6 packages from Qt 5.5.1 MaintenanceTool ([Image](http://s18.postimg.org/usxfrf9qh/packages.png)) and I installed Universal Windows packages from VS 2015, so I think Win SDK installed. Then I installed Windows 8 Phone packages from VS 2015. But Win 10 Mobile packages is disabled on the Qt Creator ([Image](http://s7.postimg.org/wqdtw2ybv/kits.png)). How can I develop Win 10 Mobile apps with Qt? Thanks.

Edit: Debugger not found: [MSVC](http://s16.postimg.org/psnjcprxx/qtmsvc32.png), [win rt armv7](http://s11.postimg.org/wx80cxp6b/qtwinrtarmv7.png), [win rt 32 bit](http://s21.postimg.org/p12ia23ef/qtwrt32.png)

Comment: Hovering over the entries with error markings should allow you to discover what is preventing the kits from being usable.

Comment: How to solve the problem depends on what the problem is. Hovering your mouse over the problematic entries will show you what the problem is.

Comment: I edited my first message.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Visual Studio 2013 to develop Windows Phone applications. If you want to develop WindowsRT applications you can use Visual Studio 2015.

Look at the picture with packages. There is information which version you should use to develop specific applications.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw Qt 5.6 is supporting VS 2015 and Windows 10 Mobile in Qt web page. I am confused because is not enough installing VS 2015 to develop Windows 10 Mobile with Qt 5.6? What should I installing for Qt 5.6 Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: You should fix your path to cdb. Did you install Windows Driver Kit?
Try to install it from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the debugging tools for windows, which are only available through the [Windows SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk). You can select only the debugging tools, and leave the rest of the SDK as it was.